# For loop repeats the same line when writing to output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder of 295 text files with each one containing a couple rows of data that I need to condense. I want to open one file, grab two lines from that file, and combine those two lines into another text file I've created, then close the data file and repeat for the next.

I currently have a for loop that does mostly that but the problem I run into is that the for loop copies the same text of the first instance 295 times. How do I get it so that it moves onto the next list item in the filelist? This is my first program in Python so I'm pretty new.

My code:

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir('/colors')
colorlines = []

for x in filelist:
    with open('/colors/'+x, 'rt') as colorfile:         #opens single txt file for reading text as colorfile
        for colorline in colorfile:                     #Creates list from each line of the txt file and puts it into colorline
            colorlines.append(colorline.rstrip('\n'))   #removes the paragraph space in list
        tup = (colorlines[1], colorlines[3])            #combines second and fourth line into one line into a tuple
    str = ''.join(tup)                                  #joins the tuple into a string with no space between the two
    print(str)
    
    newtext = open("colorcode_rework.txt","a")          #opens output file for the reworked data
    newtext.write(str+'\n')                             #pastes the string and inserts a new line
    newtext.close()
    colorfile.close()
```

Comment: You are appending ***all files*** to the same `colorlines` list but always taking the same two elements: `colorlines[1], colorlines[3]` which are of the first file... Just move `colorlines = []` ***inside*** the loop

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the color line list for each file. AS you are calling a specific item in the list (1 and 3) you are always calling the same even though more items have been added.

To reset the colorline list for each file:

```
for x in filelist:
  colorlines = []
```